# return one value from database with mysql php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im not trying to use a loop. I just one one value from one column from one row. I got what I want with the following code but there has to be an easier way using PDO.

```
try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=advlou_test', 'advlou_wh', 'advlou_wh');
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

$userid = 1;

$username = $conn->query("SELECT name FROM `login_users` WHERE username='$userid'");
$username2 = $username->fetch();
$username3 = $username2['name'];

echo $username3;
```

This just looks like too many lines to get one value from the database. :\

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could create a function for this and call that function each time you need a single value. For security reasons, avoid concatenating strings to form an SQL query. Instead, use prepared statements for the values and hardcode everything else in the SQL string. In order to get a certain column, just explicitly list it in your query. a `fetchColumn()` method also comes in handy for fetching a single value from the query

```
function getSingleValue($conn, $sql, $parameters)
{
    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute($parameters);
    return $q->fetchColumn();
}
```

Then you can simply do:

```
$name = getSingleValue($conn, "SELECT name FROM login_users WHERE id=?", [$userid]);
```

and it will get you the desired value.

So you need to create that function just once, but can reuse it for different queries.

This answer has been community edited addressing security concerns

Comment: It's dangerous to use concatenation to build a database query. Much better to use a PDO prepared statement.

Comment: Dude. Just use prepared queries, even if it's only an example. Beginners might copy this!

Comment: Even with the edits this is still a poor answer. Where does `$conn` come from?

Comment: Mind if I edit your answer to make it less dangerous and more to the point?

Comment: @YourCommonSense you don't have to ask other users for permission to edit their answers. You are free to improve it in case it would really help and you feel like it.

Answer (score 68):

You can use `fetchColumn()`:

```
$q= $conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM `login_users` WHERE username=?");
$q->execute([$userid]);
$username = $q->fetchColumn();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like it's far too much work to have to get into your car, drive to the store, fight your way through the crowds, grab that jug of milk you need, then fight your way back home, just so you can have a milkshake.

All of those stages are necessary, and each subsequent step depends on the previous ones having been performed.

If you do this repeatedly, then by all means wrap a function around it so you can reuse it and reduce it down to a single `getMyValue()` call - but in the background all that code still must be present.

Comment: "All of those stages are necessary"
No, they're not. And you should walk to the shops. ;-)

Comment: I realize it was a different time, but this is really just a comment.