# convert array object from database to string

Tags: php, arrays, database, string

I'm currently coding a blog to get experience with php.

In the edit.php I want to give the category of a post if a post has one.
This is the `edit.php`:

```
    <div class="categories-heading">
    <?php if (!empty($entry->c_Id)): ?>
      <div class="category-heading">
        <h3>Category: <?php echo e($categoryFromId); ?></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="category-heading">
        <h3>change category</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form method="post">
      <div class="categories-post-edit">
        <?php foreach($categories as $cat): ?>
          <div class="category-post-edit">
            <input type="radio" name="category" value="<?php echo e($cat->id); ?>">
              <label> <?php echo e($cat->category); ?></label>
            </input>
          </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </div>
    </form>
  <?php else: ?>
    <div class="category-heading">
      <h3>choose category</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form method="post">
    <div class="categories-post-edit">
      <?php foreach($categories as $cat): ?>
        <div class="category-post-edit">
          <input type="radio" name="category" value="<?php echo e($cat->id); ?>">
            <label> <?php echo e($cat->category); ?></label>
          </input>
        </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is the part of the function `edit()` in the `PostsAdminController.php` which is relevant for this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['title']) AND !empty($_POST['subheading']) AND 
!empty($_POST['content'])
AND !empty($_POST['category'])) {
  $entry->title = $_POST['title']; 
  $entry->subheading = $_POST['subheading'];
  $entry->content = $_POST['content'];
  $entry->c_Id = $_POST['category'];

  $this->postsRepository->update($entry);

  $savedSuccess = true;
 }
 $categoryFId = $this->categoryRepository->oneCategory($entry->c_Id); 

 $categoryFromId = $categoryFId['category'];
 var_dump($categoryFromId);

 $this->render("post/admin/edit", [
  'entry' => $entry,
  'savedSuccess' => $savedSuccess,
  'categories' => $categories,
  'categoryFromId' => $categoryFromId
 ]);
}
```

And this is the function `oneCategory` in the `CategoryRepository.php` that interacts with the database.

```
public function oneCategory($id)
{
 $table = $this->getTableName();
 $model = $this->getModelName();

 $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT `category` FROM `$table` 
 WHERE id = :id"); 

 $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $model);
 $oneCategory = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);

 return $oneCategory;
}
```

`oneCategory()` gives out an array no matter if I put `SELECT *` or `SELECT category` in the query, that's why I put `$categoryFId['category']` into a variable after.

**It works, but I think there must be a more easy or quicker way (like special functions or so), I just didn't manage to find what I search for**

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you want.  If you want `oneCategory()` to return a single element of an array, just do `return $oneCategory['category'];`  That being said, are you sure that you're getting an _array_ and not an _object_?

Comment: Unclear for me too, but my guess is the same with Patrick. You want your function to only return the string value not an array? if so take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928136/return-one-value-from-database-with-mysql-php-pdo

Comment: What I want is that $categoryFromId is a string like for e.g. ("Horror"). So the way I get the value that's at 'category' is okay I assume?

Comment: Yes, in your case your function returns the query result as array and you save only the "category" into a variable and then use it. That is one way of doing it, but you could also make the function to return that value instead of array.

Comment: Alright, thank you :)